# How do i fill dataset with openxml(excel)

Tags: c#, excel, dataset, openxml

i was able to get excel data and properties with

```
DataSet Excel = new DataSet();
Excel.ReadXml(@"C:\Excel.xml");
```

any idea how to get all excel data and properties without converting the excel to xml extensions?

i currently looking into documentformat.openxml and get stuck whereby i had to add each of the "tables" individually.

```
IEnumerable<Row> dataRows = from row in orderSheet.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>() select row;
```

Comment: I believe that most of the modern Excel files have XML content, thus it is not strange at all that you load xml content when you read the excel content.

Comment: ya, however, i wish to load excel directly without converting it to xml